# How do I show continuity in this scenario?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have that $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is real and differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$. I also have that $f'$ is bounded in some neighbourhood of 0.

I want to show that both $f$ and $f'$ are continuous at $0$. Since $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$ it must be continuous at $0$, but I am not sure how to use the given information to show continuity of $f'$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. Consider the function $$f(x) = x^2 \sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$$ We have:

1. $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$, with $f'(x) = -\cos(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$, and $f'(0) = 0$.
2. Therefore $f'$ is everywhere bounded in magnitude by $1$.
3. However, its derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$.